# Pyspark calculate average of non-zero elements for each column

Tags: pyspark

```
 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
 from pyspark.sql import functions as F
 
 spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
 df = spark.createDataFrame([(0.0, 1.2, -1.3), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                             (-17.2, 20.3, 15.2), (23.4, 1.4, 0.0),], 
                             ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
 
 df1  = df.agg(F.avg('col1'))
 df2  = df.agg(F.avg('col2'))
 df3  = df.agg(F.avg('col3'))
```

If I have a dataframe,

```
ID COL1 COL2 COL3  
1  0.0     1.2    -1.3  
2  0.0     0.0     0.0  
3 -17.2   20.3    15,2
4  23.4   1.4     0.0
```

I want to calculate mean for each column.

```
   avg1 avg2 avg3
1   3.1  7.6  6.9
```

The result of above code is 1.54, 5.725, 3.47, which includes zero elements during averaging.

How can I do it?

Comment: You should share the code snippets that you have tried and what are the issues that you have faced during the same. Will make it easier to help and explain where you are doing wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry. I added my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None values are not affecting average so if you turn zero values to null you can have average of none zero values

```
(
    df
    .agg(
        F.avg(F.when(F.col('col1') == 0, None).otherwise(F.col('col1'))).alias('avg(col1)'),
        F.avg(F.when(F.col('col2') == 0, None).otherwise(F.col('col2'))).alias('avg(col2)'),
        F.avg(F.when(F.col('col3') == 0, None).otherwise(F.col('col3'))).alias('avg(col3)'))
).show()
```